# Get my windows 8 key after replacing a hard disk

Tags: windows-8

I bought a new hard disk and installed windows 8 from some usb I prepared, My, question is, how can I get my product key from the bios or my Microsoft account, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If windows8 was preinstalled when you bought the computer it most likley had a OEM key, that key is no longer valid for your usage as it's no longer the preinstalled version.

You may have recovery disks (or partitions) at your disposal they would restore the key and the preinstalled version of windows.

The key is not saved to bios or similar the only way from the machine you would had gotten the key is if you had extract it before reinstallation.

But most large producers put stickers with the key on the computer.

Comment: Microsoft won't help? it's the same lap top...

Comment: If it was pre-installed they won't help. It's actually against the OEM agreement to reinstall the operating system (or even take a full backup), but not to restore if you have a restore disk or partition.